# How to listen for changes in textarea from directive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a textarea that looks like this:

```
    <textarea ng-controller="text" autoexpand id="tasks" ng-focus="uncheckAll()" ng-change="processText()" ng-model="tasks.tasks"></textarea>
```

The directive autoexpand is adding rows to the textarea based on how many lines you write. (it has nowrap set in css)

```
//adding rows to the textarea based on the number of newlines.
directive('autoexpand', function($timeout){
    function expand(element){
        var count = element.val().split('\n').length+1;
        element.attr('rows', count)
    }
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element){
        //onload
        $timeout(function(){
            expand(element);
        });
        element.on('keydown', function (){
                console.log('change')
                expand(element)
            });
        }

    }
}).
```

This works when I update the textarea by writing to it, but sometimes, It's updated from the model. How can I run `expand()` also in that case (I tried `element.on('change'...`, `element.change(` and `element.bind('change'` but it doesn't seem to trigger at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to listen to and react to the model (instead of the element) whenever possible.  You can have a `$watch` in the directive that will fire whenever the model changes (regardless of *how* it changes):

```
scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(){
    expand(element);
});
```

You don't even need the `keydown` event handler anymore.  The only other thing you need to do is add `ng-trim="false"` to the text area.  Otherwise, the model will ignore whitespace (including any new lines that you type).

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/0atmgOEDk9hi7Eyz7Zld?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

You should be listening for change on `ngModel` this way:

```
// here "model" is linked to ng-model property
scope.$watch("model", function() {
   console.log("Changed");
   expand(element);
});
```

Though you can certainly watch `'tasks.tasks'`, it will be limiting the usefulness of your directive to just one use case.

Answer (score 0):

you can listen in on ngModel changes by doing somethign like this:

```
scope.$on("ngModel", function(){
    //this will fire when ng model changes
}, true);
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to trigger, Do I need to add the scope or run it somewhere else or something?